# jQuery show&hide menu basics

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a doble menu, with click function and hide&show basics, but I don't understand why is not working, can you help me out? Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#work').click(function(event){
    $(this).addClass("activado"); // add active class
    $("#other,#contacto").removeClass("activado"); // remove active class
    $("#menuother").hide();
    $("#menuwork").show();
});

$('#other').click(function(event){
    $(this).addClass("activado");
    $("#work,#contacto").removeClass("activado");
    $("#menuwork").hide();
    $("#menuother").show();
});

$('#contacto').click(function(event){
    $(this).addClass("activado");
    $("#work,#other").removeClass("activado");
    $("#menuwork").hide();
});
});
```

And my html is very basic, i don't think you need it, the script speaks it self. The active class is working, but the hide & show is not.

Thanks a lot.

//edit
By the way, I'm hiding the menus in css.

//edit adding html

```
<a href="#" id="work" class="inactivo">TopMenu</a>
<a href="#" id="other" class="inactivo">TopMenu</a>
<a href="#" id="contacto" class="inactivo">TopMenu</a>

<div id="#menuwork">
<a href="#" id="SubMenu1" class="inactivo">SubMenu</a>
<a href="#" id="SubMenu2" class="inactivo">SubMenu</a>
<a href="#" id="SubMenu3" class="inactivo">SubMenu</a>
</div>

<div id="#menuother">
<a href="#" id="SubMenu4" class="inactivo">SubMenu</a>
<a href="#" id="SubMenu5" class="inactivo">SubMenu</a>
<a href="#" id="SubMenu6" class="inactivo">SubMenu</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe the menu is shown but the size of it is not? What is the HTML and CSS of the menu?

Comment: Already checked that, also I add a border to see if it works, no luck there. I'll the html and css.

Comment: We need the HTML and CSS. Reproduce it all on http://jsfiddle.net/, save it and give us the link.

Comment: this makes no sense .. not without complementary html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, remove the `#` from the ID's in your `div` elements. For example:

```
<div id="#menuwork">
```

should be:

```
<div id="menuwork">
```

Comment: Oh my god :S That was the problem, i'm very sorry, i feel like an idiot right now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @kinduff: No problem! It happens to us all!

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you create menus .. ehh ...

http://jsbin.com/itolul/13/edit#preview

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without having to make classes for active and inactive

http://jsfiddle.net/xQ64g/16/